# Counting some special derangements

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

A *derangement* of a list of $n$ distinct entries is a permutation of that list such that no corresponding entries match.  It is well-known that the number of such derangements is the nearest integer to $n!/e$ where $e$ is the base of natural logarithms.

Let's say that a permutation of a list is a $\mu$-*derangement* if both it and its reverse ordering are derangements.  Equivalently, iff the permutation is a derangement both of the original list and of the reverse of the original list.

How many $\mu$-derangements of the list $[1,2,..,n]$ are there?  Is there an exact formula?  A good approximation or bound?

There are no $\mu$-derangements for $n \lt 4$, except in the trivial case of an empty list.  I got counts for $n \le 10$ below by enumerating possibilities with a bit of Prolog code:

```
 n | # of µ-derangements 
---+----------------------
 4 |           4
 5 |          16
 6 |          80
 7 |         672
 8 |        4752
 9 |       48768
10 |      440192
```

The OEIS has [this sequence as A003471](http://oeis.org/A003471), with a recurrence relation that suggests some separation into even and odd terms might simplify things.

Comment: I think you mean $n!/e$- is it really the nearest integer to that? I know that the probability that a permutation is a derangement is close to $1/e.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Just so, Geoff.  Fixed!

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Peter Cameron's [Lectures on Derangements](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/pretty_structures/pdf/pcameron-ps11.pdf) presents three proofs that the number of derangements is the closest integer to $n!/e$, the first being the most elementary.

Comment: Empirically, both sets of values seem to be asymptotic to $n!/e^2$.  The dominant error term appears to be $1/n$ for even values of $n$ and $1/(2n^2)$ for odd values.  Probably an asymptotic expansion is possible based on the recurrence relation?

Comment: Note that the very rough approximation $(1- \frac{2}{n})^n$ gives the right answer asymptotically for the probability that a permutation is this kind of derangement, even though it (unjustifiably) treats the choices as independent. The heuristic argument is that for a given permutation $\sigma,$ there are two values of $\sigma(i)$ which are not permissible.

Comment: I [proposed an edit](https://oeis.org/draft/A003471) to the OEIS sequence adding the integral formula.

Comment: Thanks for that (proposed) addition, @joriki!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $n=2k$, this is equivalent to [What's the General Expression For Probability of a Failed Gift Exchange Draw](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73341/whats-the-general-expression-for-probability-of-a-failed-gift-exchange-draw), with a slot and its reverse partner forming a couple – the answer for this case is

$$\int_0^\infty\left(x^2-4x+2\right)^k\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx\;,$$

and I derived in the answer to the other question that this goes as $n!/\mathrm e^2$ for large $n$.

For $n=2k+1$, there's a single slot without a partner which leads to a factor $-L_1(x)=x-1$, so the answer for this case is

$$\int_0^\infty\left(x^2-4x+2\right)^k(x-1)\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx\;.$$

The asymptotic analysis remains essentially unchanged, so this also goes as $n!/\mathrm e^2$ for large $n$.

Comment: Danke shön, joriki!  The application that motivated me [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92752/color-an-n-times-n-square-with-n-colors/93261#93261) was for an $n = 2k$ even term case, trying to optimize the search strategy there.  Your answer nicely sheds light on why the even and odd term cases differ by a little.  Since $\int_0^\infty x^k e^{-x} dx = k!$, one can in principle expand your integral formula into a summation involving factorials.

Comment: @hardmath: It does seem so; expand the polynomial power with the multinomial formula, and then replace the integrals with factorials... if there was a recurrence relation for these, I wouldn't be surprised.