# How to find the recurrence sequence of the generalized Derangement?

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

I recently learned about the generalized Derangement problem. And I know how to use Laguerre polynomials to find the general term. But it seems difficult to write programs to calculate definite integrals.

> $$(-1)^{n_1+n_2+...+n_k}\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x}\prod_{i=1}^k \{ L_{ni}(x)\} \ dx $$

So I wonder if there is a way to find the recursive sequence of the generalized Derangement, so that the Time complexity of programming is much lower.For example,the Derangement problem's recursive sequence is

> $$f(n)=(n-1)*(f(n-2)+f(n-1))$$

And in this question[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94415/counting-some-special-derangements?cuid=87CEDC8B40AD0997B4BC7BA37A62DA8B),the recursive sequence is

> $(n-3)*(3*n^3 - 36*n^2 + 137*n - 162)*a(n) = (n-5)*(3*n^3 - 27*n^2 + 71*n - 50)*a(n-1) + (n-2)*(3*n^5 - 45*n^4 + 248*n^3 - 606*n^2 + 608*n - 156)*a(n-2) - 2*(n-3)*(3*n^3 - 28*n^2 + 87*n - 94)*a(n-3) + 2*(3*n^5 - 51*n^4 + 334*n^3 - 1060*n^2 + 1650*n - 1028)*a(n-4) - 4*(n-4)*(n^2 + n - 14)*a(n-5) - 4*(n-5)*(n-4)*(n-2)*(3*n^3 - 27*n^2 + 74*n - 58)*a(n-6)$

I see this recursive sequence in [$OEISA003471$](https://oeis.org/A003471),which is provided by  Vaclav Kotesovec.

So is there any normal way to find the recursive sequence of the generalized Derangement problem?I can't find any information on this matter

Comment: The code in my answer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285008/ can be used to find the recursion as in A003471.

Comment: @Somos TY,sir.I get the right answer by running your code.But it seems that the coefficient of k is a bit large.

Comment: @Somos  TY!!!By supplying more sequence values I get the concise and clear answer.Sincere respect to you