# How many to color the fields of a chessboard?

Tags: combinatorics

From Pavle Mladenović's Combinatorics: A Problem-Based Approach

How many ways are there to color the fields of a chessboard $8 \times 8$ using $8$ colors, such that every color appears in each row, and no two adjacent fields in the same column are of the same color?

Since the derangement formula is !$n = \frac{n!}{e}$. 
Will this just be $\frac{8!}{e}$?

Comment: $\frac{n!}{e}$ isn't an integer. It's very close to $!n$, though.

Comment: Maybe this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92752/color-an-n-times-n-square-with-n-colors?rq=1 answers your question?

Comment: @BMath No, that's a different, more restrictive constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but you're thinking too small.

There are $8!$ ways to colour the *first* row (and we are already beyond your $!8$ suggestion). Then there are $!8$ ways to colour the second row.  And then there are $!8$ ways to colour the third row. And so on.

So the answer is that there are $8!\cdot (!8)^7$ ways to colour the chessboard under these restrictions.